# assign individual vector element to individual columns by rown and by name - r

Tags: r, data.table

I work mostly with data table but a data frame solution would work as well.
I have the result of an apply which returns this data structure

```
applyres=structure(c(0.0260, 3.6775, 0.92
), .Names = c("a.1", "a.2", "a.3"))
```

Then I have a data table

```
coltoadd=c('a.1','a.2','a.3')
dt <- data.table(variable1 = factor(c("what","when","where")))
dt[,coltoadd]=as.numeric(NA)
```

Now I would like to add the elements of applyres to the corresponding columns, just one row at a time, because applyres is calculated from another function. I have tried different assignments but nothing seems to work. Ideally I would like to assign based on column name, just in case the columns change order in one of the two structures.

This doesn't work

```
dt[1,coltoadd]=applyres
```

I also tried

```
dt[1,coltoadd := applyres]
```

And tried to change applyrest to a matrix or a data table and transpose.
I would like to do something like this

```
dt[1,coltoadd[i]]=applyres[coltoadd[i]]
```

But not sure if it should go in a loop, doesn't seem the best way to do it.
How do I avoid doing single assignments if I have a large number of columns?

Comment: `dt[1, (coltoadd) := as.list(applyres)]`

Answer (score 0):

**1) data.frame** Convert to data.frame, perform the assignments and convert back.

```
DF <- as.data.frame(dt)

DF[1, -1] <- applyres
# perform remaining of assignments

dt <- as.data.table(DF)
```

**2) loop** Another possibility is a for loop:

```
for(i in 2:ncol(dt)) dt[1, i] <- applyres[i-1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a loop as well. Why data.table cannot do the same assignment used in a data frame? Seems trivial.